# SharePoint WSS 3.0 / show only limited number of people seen in SharePoint Group

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

Dont know if this is even possible.  But, in sharepoint wss is it possible to force sharepoint to only let users see specific people in their group?   For example, if a Sharepoint Group has 100 people in it, then I want the user to see themselves, the head of that SharePoint Group, and the CEO.

Can audience targeting be used in WSS to do this?

Is there another way to achieve this goal?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, no.  That said you can roll your own page to display the members of a SharePoint group and have it work the way YOU want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Such functionality only works out of the box with MOSS, and still requires some minor 'hacking' and that the team is properly configured in A.D. (not SharePoint Groups).

For similar webparts check [this msdn forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/9f32e0c9-1830-4dde-99bf-a68aa185e7f7) link (and still, never considering SharePoint Groups, that's very custom and should be developed as JD said)